# How to pass file expansion patterns across an ssh/rsync connection

Tags: command-line, ssh, rsync

I'm new to macOS but I have some experience in Linux. Now I am encountering some problems with different styles of command lines between macOS and Linux and I hope someone can help me.

In Linux, if I want to copy a large number of files, for example,
`apple1.png`, `apple2.png`, ..., `apple1000.png`, `banana1.png`, `banana2.png`, ..., `banana1000.png` from `dir1/` to `dir2/`,

I can use the command of:

Linux: `cp dir1/{apple*.png,banana*.png} dir2/`

But this does not work in macOS, because it does not recognize what `{apple*.png,banana*.png}` means. Right now, my best try on Mac is to copy apples and bananas separately, like

macOS: `cp dir1/'apple*.png'  dir2/`
macOS: `cp dir1/'banana*.png' dir2/`

So I would like to know if there is an equivalent in macOS that can copy both apples and bananas in one single command like the one in Linux.

---

Edit:

Thank you for your comments. I am using zsh on my macbook. The suggested command lines work well when I test them locally. But what I really want to do is to `rsync` files from a remote server.

Following the comments, `ls` in different ways give

```
jiaqing@macbook % ssh jiaqing@remote_server ls path_to_files/
apple1.png
apple2.png
apple3.png
...
banana1.png
banana2.png
banana3.png
...
orange1.png
orange2.png
orange3.png
...
```

```
jiaqing@macbook % ssh jiaqing@remote_server ls path_to_files/apple*
zsh: no matches found: path_to_files/apple*
```

```
jiaqing@macbook % ssh jiaqing@remote_server ls path_to_files/'apple*'
path_to_files/apple1.png
path_to_files/apple2.png
path_to_files/apple3.png
...
```

With zsh on my macbook `rsync` works with `rsync -azhP jiaqing@remote_server:path_to_files/'apple*' ./` and also for `'banana*'`. But it does not work with the following

```
jiaqing@macbook % rsync -azhP jiaqing@remote_server:path_to_files/{apple*,banana*} ./
zsh: no matches found: jiaqing@remote_server:path_to_files/apple*
```

```
jiaqing@macbook % rsync -azhP jiaqing@remote_server:path_to_files/{'apple*','banana*'} ./
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/d9889869-120b-11ee-b796-7a03568b17ac/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(1170) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Anything using wildcards in `zsh` usually benefits from having quotes round it to pass the args along unmolested, unless the intention is to use `zsh` in all its glory. Otherwise `zsh` tries to expand the list rather than let the tool being used do it. Specifically for `rsync` you want the remote partner to do the file selection.

It looks like you are only quoting part of the wildcard, so the curly brackets are letting the local `zsh` do something unexpected. eg.

```
jiaqing@remote_server:path_to_files/{'apple*','banana*'}
```

Instead try quoting the whole arg to pass it to the remote, eg.

```
'jiaqing@remote_server:path_to_files/{apple*,banana*}'
```